# Delimiter Change from , (comma) to | (pipe) in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a .csv format file where I have to change the delimiter ',' to '|'

here is my first few line of the CSV file:

```
BAB6-952AE17E8F65,ABCDEFG,North Lakhimpur,ASSAM,Passed,11/16/2022
BF72-A0DFA8FB69B0,PQRS,Pune,Maharastra,Not Passed,11/16/2022
9ED9-8DC499FA3659,LMNOPQO,MLP & Banglore(Series 1985),Not Passed,11/13/2022
A8EE-E811F6C05BD2,FMD,ALi Bagh,Jaipur,Haryana,Passed,11/16/2022
```

[image: CSV file image]

There are four delimiter point I have marked.My code is working fine to convert delimiter , to |.  But the problem is after 2nd delimiter. that was the address column and there are including commas(,) in the string which are not to be change.
But when I ran my code, it of course change all commas to |.
How can I handle it? and there are NO fixed length from the beginning,
1st column is fixed length but 2nd is not.

here is my code:

```
 ..............
 ..............
files.forEach(path => {
 
  console.log('File Path => ' +path);
    const fs = require('fs')
    let counter = 0;
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          const formatted = data.replace(/,/g, function(a) {
        counter++;
        return '|';
     });

     console.log(counter +  Numbers of delimiter Replaced Successfully.)

     fs.writeFile(path, formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have 5 parts.
When you Split with comma, 1st and 2nd are ok as are last one and previous last one.
If you got n parts, take  1,2 concat 3 up to n-2, hen n-1, n.
(I have non computer to five code here. Take Care of indices 1st one will be index 0, etc.)
Updated with sample code :

````
function changeCommaToPipe(s){     
  tablo = s.split(",");     
  front = tablo.slice(0,2).join("|");    
  middle = tablo.slice(2,tablo.length-2).join(); // default reuse comma   
  bottom = tablo.slice(tablo.length-2, tablo.length).join("|")   

 return front+"|"+middle+"|"+bottom   
}  
``` 

Results from, to : 

BAB6-952AE17E8F65,ABCDEFG,North Lakhimpur,ASSAM,Passed,11/16/2022
BAB6-952AE17E8F65|ABCDEFG|North Lakhimpur,ASSAM|Passed|11/16/2022
---------------------   
BF72-A0DFA8FB69B0,PQRS,Pune,Maharastra,Not Passed,11/16/2022
BF72-A0DFA8FB69B0|PQRS|Pune,Maharastra|Not Passed|11/16/2022
---------------------   
9ED9-8DC499FA3659,LMNOPQO,MLP & Banglore(Series 1985),Not Passed,11/13/2022
9ED9-8DC499FA3659|LMNOPQO|MLP & Banglore(Series 1985)|Not Passed|11/13/2022
---------------------   
A8EE-E811F6C05BD2,FMD,ALi Bagh,Jaipur,Haryana,Passed,11/16/2022
A8EE-E811F6C05BD2|FMD|ALi Bagh,Jaipur,Haryana|Passed|11/16/2022
---------------------   

HTH
````

Comment: Thank you , can you please help me more.
right now I am able to split the data by comma, but I don't know what should I do next,
is this will be check line by line of data then split and then replace? or what?

Comment: @WALL-E If you replace first 2 and last 2 commas, shouldn't that do the trick? Assuming address is the only field you have commas within.

Comment: Please See code i have added in main answer